# Can gradle imports ever suddenly fail?

Tags: android, maven, gradle, dependencies

In the Gradle you can import code other people have written by adding lines such as

```
compile 'com.domain.android:nameoflibrary:2.1.1'
```

What if the owners of this code suddenly decide to pull their libraries? Or if a site goes down somewhere? Does this suddenly break your app/code at all? Or by doing compile, is it downloading these dependencies to local copies in your project so they are safe? What exactly is happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once compiled those are part of your apk and cannot be pulled. 
Only at compile time would there be a chance that they have been pulled back. 
You could fork projects on github to make sure that you always have a copy.

Comment: Is there a way to "save" the dependencies to disk in case they suddenly go missing on next fetch?

Comment: You could fork them on github or download the zip files and include them in your project